# Error al utilizar scipy.signal.argrelextrema

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter, scipy

En el siguiente DataFrame, procedente de una importación de cotizaciones desde Yahoo.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import yfinance as yf
from scipy.signal import argrelextrema
from collections import deque    

start = '2011-01-01'
end = '2011-07-31'
 
ticker = 'AAPL'
yfObj = yf.Ticker(ticker)
data = yfObj.history(start=start, end=end)
# Drop unused columns
data.drop(['Open', 'High', 'Low', 'Volume', 'Dividends', 
  'Stock Splits'], axis=1, inplace=True)
```

aplico el método **scipy.signal.argrelextrema** de la siguiente manera.

```
def getHigherHighs(data: np.array, order=5, K=2):
    '''
    Finds consecutive higher highs in price pattern.
    Must not be exceeded within the number of periods indicated by the width 
    parameter for the value to be confirmed.
    K determines how many consecutive highs need to be higher.
    **order** define cuántos puntos a cada lado de nuestro pico necesitamos para etiquetar algo como un pico
    '''
    # Get highs
    high_idx = argrelextrema(data, np.greater, order=order)[0]
    highs = data[high_idx]
    # Ensure consecutive highs are higher than previous highs
    extrema = []
    ex_deque = deque(maxlen=K)
    for i, idx in enumerate(high_idx):
        if i == 0:
            ex_deque.append(idx)
            continue
        if highs[i] < highs[i-1]:
            ex_deque.clear()

        ex_deque.append(idx)
        if len(ex_deque) == K:
            extrema.append(ex_deque.copy())

    return extrema
extrema = getHigherHighs(data['Close'], order=5, K=2)
extrema
```

Me devuelve el siguiente error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In [20], line 1
----> 1 extrema = getHigherHighs(data['Close'], order=5, K=2)
      2 extrema

Cell In [18], line 12, in getHigherHighs(data, order, K)
      4 '''
      5 Finds consecutive higher highs in price pattern.
      6 Must not be exceeded within the number of periods indicated by the width 
   (...)
      9 **order** define cuántos puntos a cada lado de nuestro pico necesitamos para etiquetar algo como un pico
     10 '''
     11 # Get highs
---> 12 high_idx = argrelextrema(data, np.greater, order=order)[0]
     13 highs = data[high_idx]
     14 # Ensure consecutive highs are higher than previous highs

File ~/anaconda3/envs/yfinance1/lib/python3.9/site-packages/scipy/signal/_peak_finding.py:245, in argrelextrema(data, comparator, axis, order, mode)
    194 def argrelextrema(data, comparator, axis=0, order=1, mode='clip'):
    195     """
    196     Calculate the relative extrema of `data`.
    197 
   (...)
    243 
    244     """
--> 245     results = _boolrelextrema(data, comparator,
    246                               axis, order, mode)
    247     return np.nonzero(results)

File ~/anaconda3/envs/yfinance1/lib/python3.9/site-packages/scipy/signal/_peak_finding.py:70, in _boolrelextrema(data, comparator, axis, order, mode)
     67 locs = np.arange(0, datalen)
     69 results = np.ones(data.shape, dtype=bool)
---> 70 main = data.take(locs, axis=axis, mode=mode)
     71 for shift in range(1, order + 1):
     72     plus = data.take(locs + shift, axis=axis, mode=mode)

File ~/anaconda3/envs/yfinance1/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/series.py:889, in Series.take(self, indices, axis, is_copy, **kwargs)
    882 if is_copy is not None:
    883     warnings.warn(
    884         "is_copy is deprecated and will be removed in a future version. "
    885         "'take' always returns a copy, so there is no need to specify this.",
    886         FutureWarning,
    887         stacklevel=2,
    888     )
--> 889 nv.validate_take((), kwargs)
    891 indices = ensure_platform_int(indices)
    892 new_index = self.index.take(indices)

File ~/anaconda3/envs/yfinance1/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/compat/numpy/function.py:69, in CompatValidator.__call__(self, args, kwargs, fname, max_fname_arg_count, method)
     67     validate_args(fname, args, max_fname_arg_count, self.defaults)
     68 elif method == "kwargs":
---> 69     validate_kwargs(fname, kwargs, self.defaults)
     70 elif method == "both":
     71     validate_args_and_kwargs(
     72         fname, args, kwargs, max_fname_arg_count, self.defaults
     73     )

File ~/anaconda3/envs/yfinance1/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/util/_validators.py:154, in validate_kwargs(fname, kwargs, compat_args)
    152 kwds = kwargs.copy()
    153 _check_for_invalid_keys(fname, kwargs, compat_args)
--> 154 _check_for_default_values(fname, kwds, compat_args)

File ~/anaconda3/envs/yfinance1/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/util/_validators.py:70, in _check_for_default_values(fname, arg_val_dict, compat_args)
     67     match = arg_val_dict[key] is compat_args[key]
     69 if not match:
---> 70     raise ValueError(
     71         f"the '{key}' parameter is not supported in "
     72         f"the pandas implementation of {fname}()"
     73     )

ValueError: the 'mode' parameter is not supported in the pandas implementation of take()
```

Agradeceré ayuda para entender la causa de este error y cómo aplicar correctamente este método en éste caso.

Answer (score 0):

El error radica en que estaba aportando a la función, una lista en lugar de un np.array(). La solución es:

```
extrema = getHigherHighs(np.array(data['Close']), order=5, K=2)
```